# Detection of special wave forms

Tags: algorithm, classification, sensors

I am developing an application that reads a brightness sensor to detect the red stripe on the wheel of a [Ferraris electrical meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_meter#mediaviewer/File:ThreePhaseElectricityMeter.jpg). An easy way to detect this is to look at the data, select a threshold and then just count how often the signal goes below the threshold to detect the rotations. This however is not ideal, since the readings from the brightness sensor change depending on ambient light.

So a more elegant solution would be to actually detect the waveform, which has a very distinct pattern. I made some measurements and plotted them:

## measured in total darkness

[image: measured in total darkness]

## measured with direct light next to the ring

[image: measured with direct light next to the ring]

## measured with indirect lighting (room lamps)

[image: measured with indirect lighting (room lamps)]

The graph on the top depicts the absolute values happening and the bottom graph is the difference to the previous value.

I think the wave in the bottom graph is much easier to detect than in the top graph, because it's so smooth and the 2 waves (negative first, then positive) are roughly the same "height".

I am storing the raw sensor values in a ring-buffer and average them. So the bottom graph gets the difference between the current average and the previous average values.

EDIT: In case the question isn't clear: I need an algorithm that can detect this kind of wave form reliably. Also it shouldn't be too resource-intensive so it can run on an embedded system, such as Arduino Uno.

Comment: so...what is the question?

Comment: yeah I noticed I didn't actually ask a question, added one now.

Comment: if this were a controlled environment you would see 2 transitions int the output of the sensor(assume the wheel is white and the stripe is red). The transitions would be white->red and red->white and the graph would not look like a sin wave, it should have only the bottom part. So there's something else at play here since you are getting the higher part of the sin wave as well (which would indicate a spike in the level of light measured.

Comment: Please note that the bottom graph is a derivation - the rate of change - of the sensor values over time. It's perfectly reasonable that it first does a negative wave and then a positive wave since the value is decreased when it goes white->red, and then the value increases again when red->white happens.

Comment: 1) Take the yellow curve on the bottom. 2) Use a treshold (hysteresis) of about 1/3 and 2/3 of (max-min) 3) use that to feed a 3-state machine (neutral/negative/positive) 4) use a moving average for the max and min (decay time ~ a few cycles)